Hard Process and Parton Shower in QCD
I'm studying QCD for the first time and quite stuck in a few terminologies.

What are the "hard process" and "soft process" in QCD? What are the fundamental differences between them?
What exactly is a parton shower? Why do initial states have parton showers like final states? Why parton showers are formed?

The questions might be trivial but I can't understand it properly reading the books. Also please suggest any books/materials to study parton showers.

I figure that if you are studying it the books will eventually cover these topics no? What literature are you using and how are you studying QCD? Lectures in a classroom or entirely on your own?
